# Can't hit asp.net web on IIS from client

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I am trying to hit an asp.net 2.0 site that is sitting on another server on my network.
When I run the test site on the server it works : TomsServer:81

However what is the url to hit the same test site when I run it from a browser on another machine on the same network? I tried TomsServer/test but it returns a 404 File or directory not found. How can I access this test site?

[image]

Comment: What is your web site's path? What are your bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that IIS has an appropriate host header set up on that site and use that host name or that it is accepting all host names

Comment: I just put Host name: test. in IIS. But when i hit http://test:81 it says : IE cannot display the webpage?

Comment: does test resolve to that machine?  You may need to update DNS or hosts file